# Getting TypeError in Heroku but not on local

Tags: python, heroku, urllib

I have an app which runs fine locally, but when deployed to Heroku, gives the following error:

`TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes`

Here's a traceback instance for more information:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/app/managers.py", line 102, in run
    lang="en")["statuses"]  # Understand OR operator.
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twitter/api.py", line 267, in __call__
    url_base, method, {} if media else kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twitter/oauth.py", line 113, in encode_params
    key = self.consumer_secret + "&" + urllib_parse.quote(self.token_secret, safe='~')
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/urllib/parse.py", line 787, in quote
    return quote_from_bytes(string, safe)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/urllib/parse.py", line 812, in quote_from_bytes
    raise TypeError("quote_from_bytes() expected bytes")
TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes
```

This is frustrating me for a long time. I even tried checking dependency versions and ensured that both local and Heroku's dependencies have the same version, but nothing helped.

Comment: It looks like the app is trying to talk to Twitter API during initialization. I suspect `token_secret` is undefined on the Heroku environment. Can you check?

Comment: @rubayeet It is defined. Just checked it.

Comment: I guess these are some encoding issues. Does the `self.token_secret` contain some non-ASCII characters?

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki I don't think so. They're just English letters and numbers. And this happens on Heroku but not on my laptop!

Comment: I don't know Heroku, but can you check what is `type(token_secret)` somehow?  Or more interestingly `type(token_secret.encode('utf-8', 'strict'))`?

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki It will be difficult, since the code where `token_secret` is used is part of a third-party library, and I have the exact same library on my laptop and on cloud, but the problem only happens on the cloud. Still, I'll try doing that, but I bet it's `str`.

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki I am really not sure about the cause of this. Is it because I'm using a Mac and Heroku is running a Linux instance?